# Hiding a mounted device in nautilus

Tags: linux, bash, nautilus

I am running Ubuntu Precise.
In my /etc/init.d I have a bash script that, does the following on startup:

1. loop mounts an image on an NTFS drive. That image contains an ext2 file system with a directory named *home*
2. It then does a mount with a --rbind option that mounts the *home* within the image file onto */home*.

Works well so far, although having open files in */home* doesn't prevent the loop mount from being unmounted.

Unfortunately, Nautilus displays the loop mount in the list of removable drives with an icon that allows a user to unmount the loop mount. Unmounting the drive on which /home is mounted is not conducive to a well running system.

How can I keep Nautilus from displaying this loop mounted device?

*man udisk(7)* says that one of the 'Influential device properties in the udev database' is:

> UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE
>
> If set to 1 this is a hint to presentation level software that the device should not be shown to the user.

I assume that setting this property on the /dev/loop would tell Nautilus not to show the device.

How would I set the UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE in a bash script?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to mount the device somewhere other than under /media. I chose under /run, which allows /mnt to be used for temporary mounts.

Answer (score 6):

The answer should now be updated (at least for Ubuntu 12.10).
You don't have to write this  anymore (as was originally written in the other answer):

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
KERNEL=="sdb2", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

Instead, you should write this:

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
KERNEL=="sdb2", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

The rest is the same :)

Comment: This is also true for Fedora 19. I tried UUID but it didn't work for some reason?

Answer (score 4):

You have to write the following on `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disks.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="sdxy", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

Where `sdxy` is the partition inside `/dev`. You can easily find the partition by running `mount` (but I think you already know it).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [udisk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks#Hide_selected_partitions) page on archlinux wiki and to sum up the others answers:
Add a file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disks.rules`

### For udisk:

```
# hide the device sda1
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

### For udisk2:

```
# hide the device sda1
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"

# hide the device sda2 using UUID
# use: blkid /dev/sda2    to get the UUID of /dev/sda2
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```